# How to end stack execution at once (PHP)?

Tags: php, class, exception

I got a code that has a 50:50 probability of producing an error. It is all done in a class object. Any method in the object can produce an error. How can I do so that a function somewhere deep in the method stack would produce an error so it could be returned to the first function ran?

Like this:
 1. call function1
 2. function1 calls function2
 3. function2 calls function3
 4. function3 produces an error and delivers the array with the
    error definition right to function1

I know Exceptions are the right thing (wrapping around a function with a try-catch block), but I yet couldn't make it catch the Exception in a 3 function deep stack. How do I do that?

Comment: Exceptions are indeed what you want and they work over any number of levels. Show us your code so we can tell you why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Throw exception somewhere deep and catch it at a higher level. What don't you get from that?

Comment: Also the official manual has some examples which you may want to check out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? It rather simple, really:

```
<?php

function function1( ) {
    try {
        function2( );
    }
    catch( Exception $e ) {
        // Exception from function4 bubbles up.
    }
}

function function2( ) {
    function3( );
}

function function3( ) {
    function4( );
}

function function4( ) {
    throw new Exception( );
}
```

Comment: This will call for an 'uncaught exception' on my machine

Comment: Ooop, suddenly started working, don't know what I did wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are the correct way of do this. Catch Exception (general class) is a bad practice.

You should throw concrete/custom exceptions.

Look http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php and change your `throw` with more especific and concrete exceptions

Avoid

```
 throw new Exception('foo');
```

Instead

```
 throw new RuntimeException('foo');
```

Comment: Borderline "Not an answer" I would say because it is echo'ing what OP already knows

Comment: Sometimes a direct answer is not the solution. In this case his issue is a lack in the design.

Comment: I find that really *really* hard to tell by looking at OP's question.

Answer (score -2):

just use `try` at the level which should catch the Exception and leave the other ones unchanged.
EX:

```
try{
function1();
}
catch(Exception e){
// bla bla
}
```

As was stated, exceptions propagate until they are caught, or a crash :).

Comment: Why would you do that? Exceptions bubble up anyway. No need to do this at all.

Comment: Too painful, but I will consider using this

Comment: thought it was easy to understand (since the op wrote 'class project'). He can just use it at the level where he wants to catch the exception.